# jQuery preventing images and text from returning from the HOVER state

Tags: jquery, css, click, hover

I'm updating an old website of mine and changing the (rather sloppy) Javascript to jQuery. One problem I keep getting is that jQuery seems to be preventing the CSS Hover state from returning to the default - i.e. if you click on an image or text that has a jQuery function, it stays in the Hover state after the mouse has moved away, until you click somewhere else on the page. I'm assuming the `event.preventDefault()` line is causing it but I need to prevent the page from refreshing in case the user's input is lost. Any ideas?

This is the CSS:

```
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #C22F30;
}
```

This is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ingredientLabel").click(function(event) {
    $(this).next(".glossary").toggle(); // toggle glossary visibility
    x = $(".pubcrawlButton").position(); // work out the height of the content
    contentHeight = Math.floor(x.top)+240; 
    getScreenData(); // Reset the scrollbar
    event.preventDefault(); // stop page refresh
  });
});
```

Comment: What does `getScreenData()` do?

Comment: I've made an image-based scrollbar (I know about the accessibility issues and will be addressing them next) - getScreenData() measures the height of the various <divs> within the page. It doesn't have any effect on the CSS.

Comment: return false unfortunately doesn't help

Comment: There's nothing jQuery can do to make `:hover` stop working.  What it (and JavaScript in general) *can* do, however, is to add styles to the `<a>` element directly, styles that override the CSS.  It might help if you'd show the HTML also, and any other code that affects the `<a>` or elements containing it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - I found some old :active and :focus CSS that were 'locking' the :hovers in place. I removed them and now it's working fine. Strangely, they had no effect on Javascripted (as opposed to jQuery) links on the page!